# Concatenation of HTML string in javascript with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, html, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a HTML string using + operator and I am using ternary operator to check the condition and use appropriate class name in the div element, however the ternary operator is giving me wrong output. I don't know what I am missing out here. Can anyone please explain?

My code looks like this :

```
            fetch("./data/projects.json")
                .then(res => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then(jsonResponse => {
                    var carouselItem = ''

                    jsonResponse.data.map((image, index) => {
                        carouselItem += '<div class="carousel-item ' + index === 0 ? 'a' : 'b' + '">'
                    })

                    console.log(carouselItem);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
```

I get the following output when I run this code

```
b">b">b">b">b">
```

I expect the output should be

```
<div class="carousel-item a"><div class="carousel-item b"><div class="carousel-item b"><div class="carousel-item b"><div class="carousel-item b">
```

Answer (score 4):

`+` has [higher operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) (14) than the conditional operator (4). Your current code is equivalent to

```
carouselItem += ('<div class=carousel-item>' + index === 0) ? 'a' : 'b'
```

Not only is the comparison wrong, so is the assignment. Change to:

```
carouselItem += '<div class="carousel-item ' + (index === 0 ? 'a' : 'b') + '"> </div>';
```

so that the conditional is grouped properly. You also probably want to end the `<div` you started. Also, `.map` should only be used when you want to create a new array. When you want side-effects only, use `forEach`.

```
jsonResponse.data.forEach((image, index) => {
  carouselItem += '<div class="carousel-item ' + (index === 0 ? 'a' : 'b') + '"> </div>';
});
```

You *can* use `.map` here if you wanted, but if so, return the `<div>` you want, then join it together:

```
const carouselItem = jsonResponse.data.map((image, index) => (
  '<div class="carousel-item ' + (index === 0 ? 'a' : 'b') + '"> </div>'
))
  .join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the ternary in parentheses to make it a separate statement and prevent `+` take precedence (see @CertainPerformance's answer), or use a template string:

```js
const strA = "hello";
const strB = " world";
console.log(strA + 1 === 1 ? strB : "nope");
console.log(strA + (1 === 1 ? strB : "nope"));
console.log(`${strA}${1 === 1 ? strB : "nope"}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because its not able to parse correctly.

replace your

```
carouselItem += '<div class=carousel-item>' + index === 0 ? 'a' : 'b'
```

with brackets like below

```
carouselItem += '<div class=carousel-item>' + ((index === 0) ? 'a' : 'b')
```